# Filter by date using dtpicker

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

How can I filter by date in Crystal Report via VB 6 using `dtpicker`

My code is unfiltered but otherwise runs without error:

```
DataEnvironment2.rsCommand1.Open
DataEnvironment2.rsCommand1.Filter = "tanggal >=  #" & DTPicker3.Value & "# and tanggal <= #" & DTPicker4.Value & "#"
CR2.Refresh
CR2.Show
DataEnvironment2.rsCommand1.Close
Unload Me
```

Comment: You have  to make sure that your date ,format is the same with your datePicker format.. or make it all as STRING

Comment: i sure the format is same